# Cannot Solve Expected Declaration Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to implement the Facebook Login SDK to my application and it keeps returning this 'Expected Declaration' Error. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I have copied and pasted the code exactly as Facebook states :(

[image: Screenshot]

Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please include the actual code, and not a screenshot of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've pasted is written in Objective C, and your file is in Swift.

Check here for a Swift tutorial:
http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/

Comment: yes but i have included an Objective-C bridging header so that should be fine?

Comment: A bridging header will allow you to call ObjC methods from your swift code, but each file needs to be in one language or the other, so that the compiler can do the right thing. You can think of it as if each file has a different translation applied to it to get to the same compiled code that the device uses.

Comment: ok! Thank you for your help with this. do you know if there is a way of translating facebook's code into swift? :/

Comment: check the link I added. It'll give you a step by step tutorial in the right language.

Comment: thanks a million! :)

Comment: It seems that you're pretty new at this. If want, you can email me directly at the address on my github account (linked through my profile here), rather than posting questions to the board. Don't get me wrong, I love getting points for answers, but it's probably not the best use of StackOverflow.